# Underscore.js: Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I'm trying to load a list of objects into a template using the Underscore.js forEach method:

HTML template code:

```
<script type="text/template" id="element">
    <% _.each(data, function (element) { %>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4" id="inner-element">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="../../../img/<%= element.img %>" alt="...">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3 class="menu-food-name"><%= element.name %></h3>
                    <p class="menu-food-description"><%= element.description %></p>
                    <p class="menu-food-price text-right"><span class="label label-info" role="button"><%= element.price %></span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% }); %>
</script>
```

Javascript:

```
var elementTemplate = _.template($('#element').html(), {data: item});
that.$el.append(elementTemplate);
```

"item" is defined prior as an object array containing three elements with properties (name, description, price, and img) I want to display in the template (as shown in console.log(item)):

```
Object {0: Object, 1: Object, 2: Object}
    0: Object
        description: "grilled portobello and balsamic"
        img: ""
        name: "fungi grigliati"
        price: "7.95"
        __proto__: Object
    1: Object
        description: "baked clams"
        img: ""
        name: "vongole oreganate"
        price: "7.95"
        __proto__: Object
    2: Object
        description: "mussels marinara sauce"
        img: ""
        name: "padellata di cozze"
        price: "13.95"
        __proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

I keep getting an "Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined" error in the dev console when I try to run this code. I think I might be overlooking the functionality behind how the Underscore forEach method works. I'm assuming maybe the data I'm passing through is not formatted correctly. Any ideas/help on this would be great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error is right there, `data` is not defined. This has nothing to do with `_.each`; rather, you are using `_.template` incorrectly.

The second argument is `templateSettings`, not the data. You pass the data to the function returned by `_.template`.

```
// create template function
var elementTemplate = _.template($('#element').html());
// render the template with the given data
that.$el.append(elementTemplate({data: item}));
```

Comment: I was following many tutorials and all of them were teaching to pass the data into the _.template method. That didn't work. But putting the data into the returned function, as you said, worked perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: @FábioGomideNolasco: Underscore changed the definition of _.template() on 1.7.0. Older versions accepted `_.template(templateString, [data], [settings])`, while recent versions accepts only `_.template(templateString, [settings]) `.

Comment: If you're a fan of one-liners, you can do:
`var htmlText= _.template($('#element').html())({data: item});`

Comment: @SolomonAfiemo I'm not; don't do that, it's harder to read.

Comment: @SolomonAfiemo: Also, `_.template($('#el').html()).call(null, {data: items});` looks more readable, since you don't have an opening parenthesis immediately following a closing one.